# CSS columns vertical alignment in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, css

With the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>
    <div style="-webkit-column-width:5em;-moz-column-width:5em;">
        <ul>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In Chrome I get a weird alignment of rows:

[image: Chrome Alignment Issue]

The rows align correctly in Firefox. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have gone through your problem and find a solution why you are getting the problem in chrome.

Please  add this css to the ul tag:

```
<ul style="margin:0;">
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
        </ul>
```

I hope it will solve your problem.

[image]

**OPEN SCREENSHOT IN NEW WINDOW FOR CLARITY**

Above is the screen shot of different images of google chrome (different window sizes), you can see 1st image is your screenshot & the output of you code in google chrome in which i added three different colored borders to demonstrate the problem.

1. Border red on div.
2. Pink on ul
3. Green on li

After adding `margin:0;` on `ul` you can see different output in different viewport sizes.

Comment: Sorry, this makes no difference.

Comment: @groky acc to image you have provided i have solved the alignment issue of row, can you please specify what exactly you want so i can rectify whether i misunderstood your question or not. Could you please show us what exactly you want that will helpful to solve the issue.

Comment: The problem is that the rows don't line up - the first column's rows have a different vertical alignment to the other columns's rows. Adding margin:0 to the ul style doesn't make any difference to this when I open this page in Google Chrome.

Comment: @Groky I have added a screen shot please go through it if still i am not getting your problem please let me know.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I was applying the margin:0 to the <div>. Doh. Thanks, that fixes it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the issue is with the user agent stylesheet used by Webkit.

For reasons like this, it's always best to use a good [reset stylesheet](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/), so that all browsers start on the same footing, and then style from there.

Here is your example with a CSS reset stylesheet: http://jsfiddle.net/euw72/