# Split CellList into Columns, sorted vertically

Tags: java, gwt

I want to split the `CellList`'s contents **vertically** across three columns. See this example below (for a List containing the letters A to H).

```
A D G
B E H
C F
```

I have a single `CellList cell` that contains data provided by an `AsyncDataProvider<String>`.

The `CellList` is being displayed in a UiBinder Template. What's the easiest way to do this? So far I've only come up with:

1. Use 3 CellLists and split it manually with 3 AsyncDataProviders that you populate
2. Use a CellTable and populate the columns weirdly
3. Create a custom CellList that inserts random breakers

These are all pretty tedious and seem unintuitive. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Note that the solution can either be an HTML/CSS one or a Java one. I've looked at CSS3 solutions, but they should be cross-browser compatible and fast: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497279/css-columns-vertical-alignment-in-chrome

Comment: Why using CellTable populates the columns weirdly? Celltable will display whatever data provided by data provider. If the data provider is having the data in proper order, it will be displayed by CellTable.

Comment: I ended up just using a Grid and populating that, which would be a pretty similar process to using a CellTable. I didn't need the extra CellTable functionality anyways in this case.

Comment: My only nitpick was that using both Grid and CellTable would arrange the items horizontally, such that if you try to select the items, you'd select rows and not columns, but I kind of got over that and just went with a Grid.